# Notification Facade send static method catch exception

Tags: php, laravel

How can I catch Notification::send exception? This notification works fine, but I want to add some admin page for watching status. Notification::send method always return null regardless success or not.
Full code now:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\SendUserNotification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use App\Models\LogNotification;

class SendUserNotificationListener
{

public function handle(SendUserNotification $event)
{
    $users = $event->users;
    $notification = $event->notification;

    $logData = [];

    try {
        $send = Notification::send($users, $notification); // returned null
        $status = "success";

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $status = "error";
    }

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $logData[] = [
            "user_id" => $user->id,
            "type" => $notification->getType(),
            "status" => $status,
            "created_at" => now(),
            "updated_at" => now(),
        ];
    }

    LogNotification::insert($logData);
}
```

}

This code cant catch any exceptions in Notification::send method.

Comment: can you modify the question even more clear

Comment: if that `returned null` then there is no exception ... that method returns `void`

Comment: how can i modify it for logging any exception?

Comment: there isn't an `Exception` being thrown, or that would catch it ... what error did you see that made you think an `Exception` was being thrown?

Comment: i try to xDebug this code with some errors in code and Notification::send gets error in Router, i don't have any idea how can i get it in my catch T_T

Comment: what "errors" ?